# Why is chrome desktop getting my Location wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Im building an app that requires location. Im serving my app locally via apache and have permitted chrome to give my virtual host access to location despite being served without ssl. My coordinates are coming out wrong as  (6.5243793 3.3792057). Thats completely in another state on another part of my country. When I visit https://www.gps-coordinates.net/my-location, it gives the same location. But on firefox, https://www.gps-coordinates.net/my-location is giving me a more accurate location. On chrome mobile, im also getting a correct location Here is my code snippet

```
if(navigator.geolocation){

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    
            var lat = position.coords.latitude,
                long = position.coords.longitude;

          initMap(lat,long);
          // logging to console to find out why the map location is incorrect
          console.log(lat+" "+long)
        });
    }
```

Can someone tell me whats going on, or better yet how to find out the exact location, probably through google maps api?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome on mobile uses the GPS in your phone.

Chrome on desktop uses a service that estimates your location based on your IP address. This database is imprecise and often out of date. Firefox uses a different service, which works in the same way, but where your particular IP has a more accurate record.

Comment: Ok. But why is the map at maps.google.com extremely accurate despite being viewed on chrome. Are they using a different service, if yes do they offer an api that calculates the exact coordinates for the client?